# How to access java_home when using Chef Java cookbook

Tags: java, certificate, chef-infra, keystore, self-signed

To import a certificate in a keystore I want to access the attribute `java/java_home`.

On the Chef server I can manually read its value. It shows up as `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64` on the attribute tab.

Now I want to do the same in my Chef recipe. When I inspect the `node['java]` it shows

```
node['java']: {"jdk_version"=>"7", "arch"=>"x86_64", "openjdk_packages"=>[], "openjdk_version"=>nil, "accept_license_agreement"=>false, "set_default"=>true, "alternatives_priority"=>1062, "set_etc_environment"=>false, "ark_retries"=>0, "ark_retry_delay"=>2, "install_flavor"=>"oracle", "oracle"=>{"accept_oracle_download_terms"=>true}, "jdk"=>{"6"=>{"bin_cmds"=>["appletviewer", "apt", "ControlPanel", "extcheck", "HtmlConverter", "idlj", "jar", "jarsigner", "java", "javac", "javadoc", "javah", "javap", "javaws", "jconsole", "jcontrol", "jdb", "jhat", "jinfo", "jmap", "jps", "jrunscript", "jsadebugd", "jstack", "jstat", "jstatd", "jvisualvm", "keytool", "native2ascii", "orbd", "pack200", "policytool", "rmic", "rmid", "rmiregistry", "schemagen", "serialver", "servertool", "tnameserv", "unpack200", "wsgen", "wsimport", "xjc"], "x86_64"=>{"url"=>"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin", "checksum"=>"6b493aeab16c940cae9e3d07ad2a5c5684fb49cf06c5d44c400c7993db0d12e8"}, "i586"=>{"url"=>"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-i586.bin", "checksum"=>"d53b5a2518d80e1d95565f0adda54eee229dc5f4a1d1a3c2f7bf5045b168a357"}}, "7"=>{"bin_cmds"=>["appletviewer", "apt", "ControlPanel", "extcheck", "idlj", "jar", "jarsigner", "java", "javac", "javadoc", "javafxpackager", "javah", "javap", "javaws", "jcmd", "jconsole", "jcontrol", "jdb", "jhat", "jinfo", "jmap", "jps", "jrunscript", "jsadebugd", "jstack", "jstat", "jstatd", "jvisualvm", "keytool", "native2ascii", "orbd", "pack200", "policytool", "rmic", "rmid", "rmiregistry", "schemagen", "serialver", "servertool", "tnameserv", "unpack200", "wsgen", "wsimport", "xjc"], "x86_64"=>{"url"=>"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u45-b18/jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz", "checksum"=>"bea330fcbcff77d31878f21753e09b30"}, "i586"=>{"url"=>"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u71-b14/jdk-7u71-linux-i586.tar.gz", "checksum"=>"54899d0733d9a8697da59de79a02cc8f"}}, "8"=>{"bin_cmds"=>["appletviewer", "apt", "ControlPanel", "extcheck", "idlj", "jar", "jarsigner", "java", "javac", "javadoc", "javafxpackager", "javah", "javap", "javaws", "jcmd", "jconsole", "jcontrol", "jdb", "jdeps", "jhat", "jinfo", "jjs", "jmap", "jmc", "jps", "jrunscript", "jsadebugd", "jstack", "jstat", "jstatd", "jvisualvm", "keytool", "native2ascii", "orbd", "pack200", "policytool", "rmic", "rmid", "rmiregistry", "schemagen", "serialver", "servertool", "tnameserv", "unpack200", "wsgen", "wsimport", "xjc"], "x86_64"=>{"url"=>"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz", "checksum"=>"e145c03a7edc845215092786bcfba77e"}, "i586"=>{"url"=>"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-linux-i586.tar.gz", "checksum"=>"b5b16247f66643727d9b6d4bc7c5efda"}}}}
```

Many of the attributes I see through the web interface are accesible but unfortunately `java_home` is not there.

Can I read this value through a Chef recipe? Or is it only visible through the web interface?

Is there another way to know the location of Java?

I tried environment variable `$JAVA_HOME` which used to work but recently I noticed that this is also now nil for a Chef client run.

What is the correct way to import a certificate in a key store using Chef without being able to know the location of Java?

[image]

Comment: How do you include the java cookbook ? if you don't do it right you may never call the set_attribute_from_version recipes, but in this case the java_home should not appear on chef_server (unless you're not talking about the same machine and that's the only solution I can see according to your description). If I'm wrong, give more details about your run list. To answer one of your question: any attribute visible on the chef_server UI is accessible.

Comment: I think I fixed this by including the java cookbook before the cookbook that was trying to read java_home. I did not think the order would matter.

Comment: I does matter as the java_home attribute is populated by a recipe in the java cookbook and not by attribute files, thus the attribute is unknown until the recipe `set_attributes_from_version` has been compiled, so if you're trying to access this attribute at compile time from a previous recipe, it won't work. Best idea usually is to include_recipe 'java' at start of the cookbok needing it, so you're sure any necessary operation has been done before you try to access them.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [java cookbook](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java), then the java_home should be made available at `node['java']['java_home']`. That's what you should use in all your chef recipes, as long as they're run together with the java cookbook that will populate this value.

I presume you can't see the `node['java']['java_home']` attribute in your inspection because you just haven't set it as a node attribute / environment attribute on the chef server.

For the `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable, you should set `node['java']['set_etc_environment']` to true, (Optionally sets JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment, by default it's false).

Comment: You presumption sounds illogical as the value is visible on the chef_server, which is where the node will get the values at start of run.

Comment: hmm... not sure why you say that... the output of the inspection [Onno](http://stackoverflow.com/users/202576/onno) has copy pasted doesn't include java_home... does it??

Comment: No. But the screenshot does, so the two comes from two different nodes or there's something wrong. The attribute has not to be on the chef server as the Java cookbook should populate it (as you already said).